# Box transition won't respond to :hover

Tags: html, css, transition

I am making a whack-a-mole game at school and part of the lectures is to make my element transition its position when I hover over it. But apparently whenever I write :hover after the ".pos classes", nothing happens except for the fact that it completely ignores that class in the CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "info game";
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
}

#screen {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: game;
  height: 45vw;
  width: 80vw;
}

#background {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(background.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 44vw;
  width: 80vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

#middleground2 {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(middleground2.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 44vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

#sprite3 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully3.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 0vw;
}

.pos3:hover {
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 4vw;
}

#sprite1 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully1.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 46vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 7vw;
  top: 3.5vw;
}

.pos1:hover {
  left: 11vw;
  top: 11vw;
  animation-name: pop-out;
}

.fx1 {}

#middleground {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(middleground.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 4;
}

#sprite2 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully2.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 13vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 67vw;
  bottom: 45vw;
  transform: rotate(325deg);
}

.pos2 {
  right: 77vw;
}

.fix2 {}

#foreground {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(foreground.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.timer {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(timer.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 20vw;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0.3vw;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.girl {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(girlhappy.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 46vw;
  left: 1vw;
  bottom: 19vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.healthbar {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(lifebar.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 46vw;
  left: 10vw;
  bottom: 20vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

aside {
  display: none;
  grid-area: info;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>basic animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <nav>
      <ul>


      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <main>

    <section id=screen>

      <div id="background"></div>


      <div id="middleground2"></div>

      <div id="middleground"></div>



      <div id="foreground"></div>

      <div id="sprite1" class="box1 pos1 fx1"></div>


      <div id="sprite2" class="box2 pos2 fx2"></div>


      <div id="sprite3" class="box3 pos3"></div>



      <div class="timer"></div>
      <div class="girl"></div>
      <div class="healthbar"></div>



    </section>








    <aside>
      <p> this is where i write what the game is about</p>
    </aside>






  </main>






  <footer>



  </footer>
  <script src="addclassin.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same class for the initial state and the hover, even if your element has several classes. I.e. you have this (which applies both to the same element):

```
.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 0vw;
}

.pos3:hover {
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 4vw;
}
```

But you need to use the same selector for the hovering, i.e. like this:

```
.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 0vw;
}

.box3:hover {
  top: 4vw;
}
```

(and you can omit those settings that are identical in the initial state, like your `left` setting)

Comment: thx for the feedback. Tried to change the selector you mentioned but it still doesn't function.

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually working (at least has how you described it should), it just needs a couple of changes, especially in the classes/ids of the elements, where you are giving three classes to an element that has id, and really only need's one.

Try using absolute units https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-units.php instead of realative one's, the may give unexpected results when used in children elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "info game";
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
}

#screen {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: game;
  height: 45vw;
  width: 80vw;
}

#background {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(background.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 44vw;
  width: 80vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

#middleground2 {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(middleground2.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 44vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

#sprite3 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully3.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 0vw;
}

.pos3:hover {
  left: 50.5vw;
  top: 4vw;
}

#sprite1 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully1.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 3000;
  background-color: blue;
}

#sprite1:hover {
  left: 11vw;
  top: 11vw;
  animation-name: pop-out;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 7vw;
  top: 3.5vw;
}

.fx1 {}

#middleground {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(middleground.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 4;
}

#sprite2 {
  grid-area: game;
  background-image: url(bully2.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 13vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: gold;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 67vw;
  bottom: 45vw;
  transform: rotate(325deg);
}

.pos2 {
  right: 77vw;
}

.fix2 {}

#foreground {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(foreground.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 45vw;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.timer {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(timer.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: green;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 20vw;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0.3vw;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.girl {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(girlhappy.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 46vw;
  left: 1vw;
  bottom: 19vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.healthbar {
  grid-area: game;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(lifebar.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 46vw;
  left: 10vw;
  bottom: 20vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

aside {
  /*display: none;*/
  grid-area: info;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>basic animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <main>

    <section id=screen>

      <div id="background"></div>
      <div id="middleground2"></div>
      <div id="middleground"></div>
      <div id="foreground"></div>

      <div id="sprite1" class="box1 pos1 fx1"></div>

      <div id="sprite2" class="box2 pos2 fx2"></div>

      <div id="sprite3" class="box3 pos3"></div>

      <div class="timer"></div>
      <div class="girl"></div>
      <div class="healthbar"></div>
    </section>

    <aside>
      <p> this is where i write what the game is about</p>
    </aside>
    
  </main>
  
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="addclassin.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thx for the feedback! :) But according to our teachings we are are supposed to work with this type of styling when we are preparing for JS  like <div class=”box1 pos1 fx1”>. In this case I wrapped my element with an ID and used the mentioned transition property to style in CSS. However everytime i try to use the :hover on it doesnt react..